# Can I change SOCKS proxy within a function using SocksiPy?

Tags: python, proxy, socks

I'm trying to write a function which will take a URL and return the contents of that URL. There is one additional argument (useTor) which, when set to `True`, will use SocksiPy to route the request over a SOCKS 5 proxy server (in this case, Tor).

I can set the proxy globally for all connections just fine but I cannot work out two things:

1. How can I move this setting into a function so that it can be decided on the `useTor` variable? I'm unable to access `socks` within the function and have no idea how to do so.
2. I'm assuming that if I don't set the proxy, then the next time the request is made it'll go direct. The SocksiPy documentation doesn't seem to give any indication of as to how the proxy is reset.

Can anyone advise? My (beginners) code is below:

```
import gzip
import socks
import socket

def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

# next line works just fine if I want to set the proxy globally
# socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

import urllib2
import sys

def getURL(url, useTor=False):

    if useTor:
        print "Using tor..."
        # Throws- AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setproxy'
        socks.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
    else:
        print "Not using tor..."
        # Not sure how to cancel the proxy, assuming it persists

    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    usock = opener.open(url)
    url = usock.geturl()

    encoding = usock.info().get("Content-Encoding")

    if encoding in ('gzip', 'x-gzip', 'deflate'):
        content = usock.read()
        if encoding == 'deflate':
            data = StringIO.StringIO(zlib.decompress(content))
        else:
            data = gzip.GzipFile('', 'rb', 9, StringIO.StringIO(content))
        result = data.read()
    else:
        result = usock.read()

    usock.close()

    return result

# Connect to the same site both with and without using Tor    

print getURL('https://check.torproject.org', False)
print getURL('https://check.torproject.org', True)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Example

Simply invoke `socksocket.set_proxy` with no arguments, this will effectively remove any previously set proxy settings.

```
import socks
sck = socks.socksocket ()
```

```
# use TOR
sck.setproxy (socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
```

```
# reset to normal use
sck.setproxy ()
```

---

#### Details

By looking at the source of `socks.py`, and digging into the contents of `socksocket.setproxy`, we quickly realize that in order to discard of any previous proxy attributes we simply invoke the function with no additional arguments (besides *`self`*).

```py
class socksocket(socket.socket):
    ... # additional functionality ignored

    def setproxy(self,proxytype=None,addr=None,port=None,rdns=True,username=None,password=None):
        """setproxy(proxytype, addr[, port[, rdns[, username[, password]]]])
        Sets the proxy to be used.
        proxytype - The type of the proxy to be used. Three types
                are supported: PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4 (including socks4a),
                PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5 and PROXY_TYPE_HTTP
        addr -      The address of the server (IP or DNS).
        port -      The port of the server. Defaults to 1080 for SOCKS
                servers and 8080 for HTTP proxy servers.
        rdns -      Should DNS queries be preformed on the remote side
                (rather than the local side). The default is True.
                Note: This has no effect with SOCKS4 servers.
        username -  Username to authenticate with to the server.
                The default is no authentication.
        password -  Password to authenticate with to the server.
                Only relevant when username is also provided.
        """
        self.__proxy = (proxytype,addr,port,rdns,username,password)

    ... # additional functionality ignored
```

> <sup>**Note**: When a new connection is about to be negotiated, the implementation will use the contents of `self.__proxy` unless the potentially required element is `None` (in which case the setting is simply ignored).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately putting `sck = socks.socksocket()` outside of the function and then calling `sck.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "192.168.0.1", 9050)` inside `getURL` doesn't throw an error but doesn't route anything through tor either. Can you help with this too?